# Strange behavior of Control.Page in nested ViewUserControl

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a ASP.Net MVC view which contains other partial views derived of ViewUserControl. The view itself is contained in a master page, so the control hierarchy can be summarized as follows:

```
    Master page              - basic settings
       ViewPage              - "the" page
          ViewUserControl    - content component 1
          ViewUserControl    - content component 2
          ...
          ViewUserControl    - content component n
```

Additionally, we have a custom control for the declaration of CSS and Javascript files. This custom control ensures that, no matter how deep into the hierarchy, whenever there is a CSS or JS dependency it will be rendered inside the `Page.Header`, thus avoiding scattered and duplicated references. Let's call this custom control `<my:dependency>`.

All is well when `<my:dependency>` is hosted in the master or ViewPage. But if I use it deeper inside the content components, `Page.Header` is null. Debugging revealed that, for controls hosted in a ViewUserControl, their `Page` is the very ViewUserControl in which they're in, and so the `Header` is indeed missing.

How can I make `<my:dependency>` "see" the topmost ViewPage and get access to the `Header`? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now I could be wrong, but you appear to be trying to get a web forms control to work in MVC, something that is not recommended for reasons you've discovered.

You might want to look at something involving the ViewData collection.

Simon

Comment: I realized this some time after posting the question, and decided to approach the problem differently.